# Presto API options other than JDBC

Tags: presto

What are all the other options I have to get data to user interface from Hive through Presto query engine other than JDBC

```
UI  <--> Presto <--> Hive
```

Answer (score 6):

The best interface for UI programming is the Presto REST interface.  At Facebook we use this REST interface directly in PHP, Python and R for everything from graphical dashboards to statistical analysis.  We are working on formal documentation for the REST interface, but for now the best documentation is here:

https://gist.github.com/electrum/7710544

BTW, the current JDBC driver is just a thin wrapper around the Presto REST interface and is really just a prototype.  We are working on improving the driver for an internal project at FB, so expect it to become much better over the next few months.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a python user, there is a decent library [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) from Dropbox. [PrestoDB site](https://prestodb.io/resources#clients) lists a collection of different Presto clients.

However, all of them are wrappers on top of Presto REST API with high-level API support.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial for using pyhive to connect presto. I have tried but if I run it in the same node where presto installed then it working otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming Node.js clients

npm: lento
Lento is a popular streaming client for Presto that supports the HTTP protocol v1. It also supports keep-alive HTTP connections, Gzip and Deflate content encoding, and HTTP 503 retries.
GitHub - vweevers/lento: Streaming client for Presto HTTP protocol v1.

npm: presto-stream-client
Presto-stream-client is another popular streaming client for Presto that supports the HTTP protocol v1. It also supports keep-alive HTTP connections and Gzip content encoding.
GitHub - serakfalcon/presto-stream-client: streaming ES6 Presto client library for node.js

Distributed query engine clients

npm: presto-client
This is a popular client library for Presto that provides a simple and easy-to-use API for connecting to and querying Presto.